# ant to maven conversion: correct approach?

Tags: maven, ant, maven-plugin

I am tasked with converting a java project which is created with `ant` to `maven`.

This is how the project is set up.

1. All the sources are stored in `src` directory.
2. `ant`'s compiling target is to compile the entire `src` directory.
3. `ant`'s packaging target has several sub-targets.

   Each target has different jars which has `include` or `exclude` directories.

This is the approach that I took.

1. Find out all dependencies. Store them in `DependencyManagement` section of `parent pom`
2. Create a module and copy entire `src` directory.
3. compiled it.
4. Tried to create separate modules for different `jar` files.

**Problem**: the files are in-separable. Most of the files are depending on other files. I tried separating them. It results in creating cyclic dependencies. Hence, this step failed.

5. Use different profiles and `maven-jar-plugin` to `include` or `exclude` packages.

**Question 1** when I tried this `mvn install -P profile1,profile2`, `target` has only `jar` file for `profile2`. They both have `maven-jar-plugin` and each has different `finalName`.

```
    <profile>
        <id>profile1</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/src/.../profile1/**</include>
                        <finalName>profile1-lib</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Is there a different command or am I doing something wrong?

**Question 2** one of the lib has several `image` files in it.

The above approach does not copy the `image` files in the result `jar`.

I understand `maven` wants all resources in `resources` directory. I will move the images, but for now I am trying to include them in the `jar`.

I added `maven-resources-plugin`.

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>src/main/java/jpl/mipl/mdms/FileService/komodo/ui/savannah/subscription/util/resources</directory>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

When I run `mvn install -P profile1`, I can see the logs saying `Copying # resources`.

I can also see them being copied to target/classes. the path that I gave to the plug-in. But they are all copied to that directory.

I want to retain the structure, and the result `jar` still doesn't have it.

**Answer:** I have to move them to `resources` directory. `maven` is strict.
Anything that I should be doing differently?

**Extra Question** Am I using the correct plug-ins? Or is there more efficient plug-ins that I should be using?

Thank you.

Comment: Having directories which are being packaged into separated jar files in Ant means having different modules in Maven....If you been caught by cycle dependencies your decoupling is not correctly done...using profiles to run maven-jar-plugin is the wrong setup...

Comment: I doubt that too. I switched to profiles since I wasted like 10 hours decoupling. I will try it again.

Comment: If you migrate such projects you learn the issue you have with decoupling...I'm supporting a bigger project as well and first they blamed Maven to go the wrong way but after a time they realized that it was the problem of the software...;-)

Comment: Thanks. I managed to decouple them. took some time, but I did it. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to Question1** : You  have missed the `</includes>` tag.(Probably because of the stackoverflow formatting!). I am not sure whether you can execute a maven command on two profiles at a time. when you do so, only the second profile gets executed. Try executing the command on each profile separately.

**Answer to Question2**: You have missed the `<resources>` opening tag.(Probably because of the stackoverflow formatting!). Moreover, if you want to retain the structure, you can mention the structure too in the `<outputDirectory>` tag, something like the below:

```
<outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/src/main/java/jpl/mipl/mdms/FileService/komodo/ui/savannah/subscription/util/resources</outputDirectory>
```

This may look insane!, but may work if you have few resources directory. If you have more resources, then this may become cumbersome. But anyways, check whether this can be helpful!